# Calling Prolog from R

Tags: r, prolog, ffi

It is possible to call R from within Prolog, using a [library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/real/prolog/real.pl)  recently implemented in SWI and YAP Prolog variants.

Reciprocally, is there any way of calling Prolog from within R ? In the absence of a direct R - Prolog interface capable of binding Prolog terms to R just as Rcpp binds C++ objects to R objects, is there any indirect way to achieve this aim (like calling Prolog from C++ code embedded in R code via Rcpp)?

By ’calling’, I mean ’linking’ prolog terms to R objects, as is possible for C++ objects using Rcpp, and executing prolog queries through R function wrappers, without resorting to operating system calls.

Comment: (I don't know R for such details, but) the general interface used from the command line should be good enough for many cases. Or  named pipes.

Comment: I may have been not specific enough about what I meant by ’calling’. I hope the edit corrects this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog and YAP you can use library [real](http://stoics.org.uk/~nicos/sware/real/), written by Nicos Angelopoulos and Vitor Costa Santos.

With this library it is not only possible to call R from within Prolog, but you can even share datastructures between Prolog and R (e.g., Prolog lists <-> R matrices)!

An earlier version was [published at PADL 2013](http://www.stoics.org.uk/~nicos/pbs/padl2013-real.pdf). The current version uses some of the recent changes in SWI7, e.g. use of the dot for function application, to make the integration between SWI-Prolog and R even more seamless.

Comment: R..eal is the lib linked to in the original question. Thanks for your suggestion, I’ll have a go at testing ’shared’ structures and come back with results. However available research papers do not even suggest how to trigger Prolog queries from R.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the prolog the command line interface via `system` or `system2` in R.

If you're serious about this, you could consider writing an R package with `Rcpp` that calls prolog via the `SWI-Prolog.h` [C++ interface](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/pl2cpp.html).

ps: OMG I learned programming in prolog! Totally forgot about it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I'm not an R programmer... but I have an advice: [use](http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/http/index.txt) the SWI-Prolog HTTP server library.

I can see [from a quick search](http://gastonsanchez.com/work/webdata/getting_web_data_r5_json_data.pdf) that R has HTTP interfaces (with JSON), so the amount of glue code should be manageable. From the architecturally viewpoint, the construction of API in SWI-prolog is currently the preferred route.

Answer (score 0):

Check this library: https://github.com/42n4/rolog forked from mogodan github user.
It can run Prolog inside R.